# How to construct key path for encapsulated Toggle accessing a collection

Tags: generics, swiftui, swift-keypath

I'm trying to build a new SwiftUI `View` that encapsulates a `Toggle`.
The `Toggle` accesses a collection so that it can show up in a mixed state.
I'm having difficulties constructing the proper `KeyPath`.

I've build the view as follows:

```
struct CornersView<C>: View where C: RandomAccessCollection  {
    @Binding var sources: C
    let keyPath: KeyPath<C.Element, Binding<ApertureCorners>>


    var body: some View {
        Toggle(sources: sources, isOn: keyPath.appending(path: \.upperLeftActive), label: {})
    }
}

#Preview {
    @State var sources = [ApertureCornerTreatment(radius: 1, corners: [], chamfered: false)]

    return CornersView(sources: $sources, keyPath: \.corners)
}
```

This gives me the following error on the last line in the preview:
`Key path value type 'ApertureCorners' cannot be converted to contextual type 'Binding<ApertureCorners>'`

Oddly enough, if I would want a Toggle on `chamfered` in the preview I would write:
`Toggle(sources: $sources, isOn: \.chamfered, label: {})`, which looks very similar to the current preview.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, please post a complete example. I've stubbed in some code to be able to reproduce your error, but you should have included all this in your post:

```
struct ApertureCorners: OptionSet {
    var rawValue: UInt8

    static let upperLeft = Self(rawValue: 1 << 0)

    var upperLeftActive: Bool {
        get { contains(.upperLeft) }
        set {
            if newValue { insert(.upperLeft) }
            else { remove(.upperLeft) } }
    }
}

struct ApertureCornerTreatment {
    var radius: CGFloat
    var corners: ApertureCorners
    var chamfered: Bool
}
```

With those definitions, I can reproduce your error:

```
struct CornersView<C>: View where C: RandomAccessCollection & MutableCollection {
    @Binding var sources: C
    let keyPath: KeyPath<C.Element, Binding<ApertureCorners>>

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(sources: sources, isOn: keyPath.appending(path: \.upperLeftActive), label: {})
    }
}

#Preview {
    @State var sources = [ApertureCornerTreatment(radius: 1, corners: [], chamfered: false)]

    return CornersView(
        sources: $sources,
        keyPath: \.corners
//               ^  Key path value type 'ApertureCorners' cannot be converted to contextual type 'Binding<ApertureCorners>'
    )
}
```

The location of the error isn't really where you have a problem, though.

The main problem is in your call to `Toggle` (line-wrapped for readability):

```
    Toggle(
        sources: sources,
        isOn: keyPath.appending(path: \.upperLeftActive),
        label: {}
    )
```

You're passing `sources`, not `$sources`. So you're passing a plain array (type `[ApertureCornerTreatment]`) to `Toggle`. The `isOn` argument therefore needs to be a `KeyPath<ApertureCornerTreatment, Binding<Bool>>`.

There are no `Binding`s in `ApertureCornerTreatment` or `ApertureCorners`, nor is there any obvious way to create one, so you're not going to be able to create a key path with that type.

The trick, which is not explained in `Toggle`s documentation, is this: whatever you pass as the `sources` argument to `Toggle` needs to be not just a `RandomAccessCollection`, but also **something that can create `Binding`s**.

The only type I'm aware of that conforms to `RandomAccessCollection` and can create `Binding`s is… `Binding` itself, when its `Value` type is itself a `RandomAccessCollection`.

So, let's change the code to pass `$sources` to `Toggle`, and get two new errors:

```
    Toggle(
//  ^  Initializer 'init(sources:isOn:label:)' requires that 'C' conform to 'MutableCollection'
        sources: $sources,
        isOn: keyPath.appending(path: \.upperLeftActive),
//                    ^  Cannot convert value of type 'KeyPath<C.Element, Binding<Bool>>' to expected argument type 'KeyPath<Binding<C>.Element, Binding<Bool>>'
        label: {}
    )
```

We fix these errors by adding a requirement that `C` conform to `MutableCollection`, and by changing the type of the `keyPath` property:

```
struct CornersView<C>: View where C: RandomAccessCollection & MutableCollection {
//                                                 ADD THIS ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    @Binding var sources: C
    let keyPath: KeyPath<Binding<C.Element>, Binding<ApertureCorners>>
//           CHANGE THIS ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(
            sources: $sources,
            isOn: keyPath.appending(path: \.upperLeftActive),
            label: {}
        )
    }
}
```

With those changes, Swift accepts the `#Preview`.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the omissions... 
I had expected that the initializer of the view had to look somehow like the initializer of the Toggle in order to work the same way. It's a mystery to me how Toggle works, but this works fine now!